# General techniques for debugging the "multiple definition of ..." error?

Tags: c++, c, debugging

I am looking for general debugging "tricks" for finding the source problem of this kind of error message:

```
build/nat.cpp.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `input::helloCounter'
build/sam.cpp.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here, input::helloCounter is a global variable defined in a header file, but the header file is well-guarded with `ifndef...`.

Pasting the source here should be pointless as there are too many. But I am wondering whether you have some general techniques for debugging in such a situation, e.g., by inserting some special code so to expose the issue? For information, I am using Ubuntu 14.04, Clang/g++ as compiler.

Comment: This isn't really a case for debugging, but for knowing what to do. You don't want to define a global in a header. You want to *declare* the global in the header (e.g., `extern int input::helloCounter;`) and define it in only one source file (e.g., `int input::helloCounter;`, optionally including an initializer with the definition). Note: if this is a static class member, the declaration in the class definition suffices--you don't need an `extern ...` declaration separately.

Comment: @Jerry Very cool advise. Thank you!

Comment: @Jerry Still, the error message reveals something wrong in the code, and I am wondering if there are some tricks for finding out the problem.

Comment: Looking for definitions of `input::helloCounter` would be the obvious place to start (hard to say much more without seeing any code though).

Comment: Minor point:  "debugging" is not the word one would usually use to find a link error (unless developing a compiler or linker).  I would say "fixing" or "resolving" the link error.  That said, just grep for every occurrence of `helloCounter` and see how many implement it:  there should be only one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mostly an implementation-specific issue. You did not specify which compiler or operating system you are using, so no help particular to your platform can be offered. However, for example, in a similar situation on Linux I would use the [nm(1)](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/nm.html) tool from [binutils](https://sourceware.org/binutils/) to search all the object code files for the ones that define the symbol, locating all the object code files which define it, and determine which ones should not have it defined.

Once it's known which object code file's definition should not be there, the corresponding source file can be examined to determine how it compiled the way it did.

I'm sure that whatever compiler or operating system you're using, it must have comparable tools that you can use in the same way.